# In Listview last option deleted, when i apply option menu , delete option on any list item, it was deleted only last item what can i do now?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

In `Listview` last option deleted, when i  apply option menu , delete option on any list item, it was deleted only last item what can i do now ? and similar problem happened when choose edit option it will select or fetch information of last item,

```
final CharSequence[] gender = {"Edit","Delete"};

         alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(StikiNotesActivity.this);
                final AlertDialog.Builder alert_del = new AlertDialog.Builder(StikiNotesActivity.this);

                alert_del.setTitle("Confirmation !");


                alert.setTitle("Options");
                alert.setItems(gender,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                 {
                     if(which==0)
                     {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EditOpetion"+alist.get(0).sid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        final Intent i = new Intent(StikiNotesActivity.this,FirstClass.class);
                        //String txt=new String();
                        i.putExtra("id",""+alist.get(position).sid);            
                        startActivity(i);


                     }
                     else if(which==1)
                     {
                         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(StikiNotesActivity.this);
                         alertDialog.setTitle("Selected Subject will be deleted");
                         alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {

                                            alist.remove(position);
                                            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                            alertDialog.show();
                     }


                 }});
```

please help me out of this problem?

Comment: From where you are getting the position?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this

1 - after clicking Ok button in Delete AlertDialog, you have to get `item position`, I propose you must implement `onItemClickListener`

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   alist.remove(position);
                   adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

2 - I propose to add a `editText` to your AlertDialog like this

```
else if(which==1){
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(StikiNotesActivity.this);

   EditText txtPosition = new EditText(YourContext);
   alertDialog.setView(txtPosition); 
   alertDialog.setTitle("Selected Subject will be deleted");
   alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

             //get the position from txtPosition
             int position = Integer.parseInt(txtPosition.getText().toString());
             alist.remove(position);
             adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
             dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
   alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
   alertDialog.show();

  }
```

hope this help you